# hadoop + ambari cluster change configuration

Tags: json, linux, hadoop, ambari

I want to upload the new bluprint.json file to my ambari cluster as the following

```
curl  -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET http://10.14.5.40:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP6?format=blueprint -o /tmp/1-HDP6_blueprint.json
```

when I run it , seems that every thing is ok because we not get any warning /error

but when I read the ambari GUI parameters I see that the new bluprint.json not affected the ambari cluster with the new configuration

how to debug this ?, or how to get notification from the curl ... syntax about what happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that curl command you used is for downloading existing cluster configuration in blueprint format (its XGET).

You will have to use curl -XPOST to register and upload new blueprint to ambari.

```
curl --verbose -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X POST -u admin:admin http://10.14.5.40:8080/api/v1/blueprints/:HDP6new?validate_topology=false --data  "@./blueprint.json"
```

Also note that, to change existing cluster configuration, uploading modified bluetooth is not correct way. You may refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Modify+configurations) document for modifying configurations.

Comment: thank you very much , is it possible to upload all blueprint.json configuration in one time ?  and if yes what is the procedure ? , second let say I want to change single parameter can you please show me example about this ?

Comment: refer to "doc"  I see there the  --> 3 Save a new version of the config and apply it as desired config  , is it mean that I can change the parameters and to take affect need then to restart the relevant service ?